# Counting occurrences of string in an arraylist using case-insensitive comparison

Tags: java, string, arraylist, case-insensitive

I have to count the occurrences of each `String` in an `ArrayList` that includes Strings and ints. Right now I have to ignore the `int` variable that corresponds to the quantity of every item and just count the repetitions of each String in that list.

My problem is that in class we only did this with ints. Now with Strings I'm having a problem with the casing because "abc" is different than "Abc" and "def of Ghi" is different from "Def of ghi".

Right now the code I have is this:

```
Map<String, Integer> getCount1 = new HashMap<>();
{
    for (ItemsList i : list) {
        Integer count = getCount1.get(i.name);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0;
        }
        getCount1.put(i.name, (count.intValue() + 1));
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : getCount1.entrySet())
        f.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

But as I said: it is not counting the occurrences correctly. I have, for example, one occurrence in my list called "Abc of abc" then in the input.txt file list I have that same occurrence 4 times - "Abc of abc"; "abc of Abc"; "Abc of Abc" and "abc Of abc" - all written differently and it's counting them separately instead of the same occurrence 4 times.

Early on when I was working on the totals and averages I was able to use `equalsIgnoreCase()` so it works fine in there, so regardless of the casing, it's counting them in the right list but not as just one occurrence several times.

Is there a way that I could use the ignore case or convert everything to the same case before counting them?

Just an **update**: Instead of trying the `.toLowerCase()` there I used it in the `FileReader` when it reads the .txt file and it worked `i.name = name.toLowerCase();`

Thanks for your time and help anyway

Comment: Too much descriptive and unclear.Please explain the need in few lines.

Comment: I need to count the Strings "abc of abc" and "Abc of abc" as the same occurrence 2 times in an ArrayList instead of different ones because of the Case

Comment: @shaoibchikate, I think its quite clear.

Comment: Fil,  did you see my answer?

Comment: yeah, was working on it now, but it seems like it doesn't really fix my issue. it worked on some of the strings but not in all of them.

Comment: Fil, which ones? Also use @Pureferret to give a notification when you reply.

Comment: @Pureferret ok, sorry about that. so here is my input list "Steak : 2"; "Tuna salad : 1"; "Steak : 3"; "Tuna salad : 1"; "Tomato Soup: 2" "tomato soup: 1"; "tuna Salad : 1". the ints don't matter, just the strings, when I put your code in there this was the output - "tomato soup: 2", "tuna salad : 1"; "steak : 1". thanks for your help

Comment: @Pureferret: The output I'm looking for is - "Steak: 2" ; "Tuna Salad : 3"; "Tomato Soup: 2". I'm new to java and I find it kinda hard to understand some things, I would just like to how this works and what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Fil, post the whole content of your input and the rest of your code.  I'll look into this properly at home.

Comment: @Pureferret  I was able to fix it, I used `.toLowerCase();` in the FileReader function when it opens the .txt file and it worked I just added it to the String line of the ArrayList `i.name = name.toLowerCase();` and got it working, thanks for your time and help, I really appreciate it

Comment: Fil,  do you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: @Pureferret I updated my post with that, but sure I'll add the answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying the `.toLowerCase()` there I used it in the `FileReader` when it reads the .txt file and it worked `i.name = name.toLowerCase();`

So in the end my code there was this:

```
static void readFile(ArrayList<Items> list) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new FileReader("input.txt")
    );
    String text;
    while( (text = in.readLine()) != null ) {
        if(text.length()==0) break;
        Scanner line = new Scanner(text);
        linha.useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*");
        String name = line.next();
        int qtt = line.nextInt();
        Items i = new Items();
        i.name = name.toLowerCase();
        i.qtt = qtt;
        list.add(i);
    }
    in.close();            
}
```

Comment: And now you can click the Green Tick to accept this as **The Answer**. (this is how Stackexchange/stackoverflow works)

Comment: @Pureferret yeah, I tried, it says I need to wait two days to accept my own answer

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
public void getCount(){
    Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for(ItemsList i : itemsList){
        if(countMap.containsKey(i.Name.toLowerCase())){
            countMap.get(i.Name.toLowerCase())++;
        }
        else{
            countMap.put(i.Name.toLowerCase(),1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Essentially yes,  but I believe the method name is `toLowerCase`

Comment: I tried this one, it gives me an error on the "countMap.get(i.Name.toLowerCase())++;" line, saying it requires a variable and found a value. Thanks for your time, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The [hashing function](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) for a HashMap is case sensitive,  so you need to uppercase or lowercase the string values. See below your modified code:

```
Map<String, Integer> getCount1 = new HashMap<>();
{
    for (ItemsList i : list) {
        Integer count = getCount1.get(i.name);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0;
        }
        getCount1.put(i.name.toString(). toLowerCase() , (count.intValue() + 1));
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : getCount1.entrySet())
        f.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

As a point of style I'd use a more descriptive name for the items in your ItemsList like `item`.